# Overlay border works but background-color doesn't

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on an overlay for my gallery items, when I check if the targeting is correct with red border it works, but when I wanna take a step further and add a background-color to it it doesn't despite of z-index set up.
What did I do wrong here? Clearfix makes no difference.

```css
.gallery {
  margin-top:50px;
}

.gallery-item {
  padding:0px;
  border:1px solid white;
  z-index:101;
  position:relative;
}

.gallery-item img {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  z-index:101;
}

.gallery-overlay {
  border:1px solid red;
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.1);
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  z-index:102;
}

.gallery-caption {
  height:50px;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="gallery clearfix col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 gallery-item">
            <div class="gallery-overlay">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/" alt="500x500">
            </div>
            <p class="gallery-caption text-center">Item caption</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 gallery-item">
            <div class="gallery-overlay">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/" alt="500x500">
            </div>
            <p class="gallery-caption text-center">Item caption</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 gallery-item">
            <div class="gallery-overlay">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/" alt="500x500">
            </div>
            <p class="gallery-caption text-center">Item caption</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- new row starts -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 gallery-item">
            <div class="gallery-overlay">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/" alt="500x500">
            </div>
            <p class="gallery-caption text-center">Item caption</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 gallery-item">
            <div class="gallery-overlay">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/" alt="500x500">
            </div>
            <p class="gallery-caption text-center">Item caption</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 gallery-item">
            <div class="gallery-overlay">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/" alt="500x500">
            </div>
            <p class="gallery-caption text-center">Item caption</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the background-color does work, but it is being covered by its contents, which in this case is the image.

If the effect is to create a translucent color wash over the image delete your z-indexes and only add a `z-index: -1` to the image itself.  That way it will tuck itself behind it's parent's background color.

Take a look at the code.  I have taken out all z-indexes and modified / added the following (and changed the background color from white to teal and its opacity from 0.1 to 0.5 to make it more pronounced):

```
.gallery-overlay {
  border:1px solid red;
  background-color:rgba(0,255,255,.5);
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
}
.gallery-overlay img {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```css
.gallery {
 margin-top:50px;
}

.gallery-item {
 padding:0px;
 border:1px solid white;
 z-index:101;
 position:relative;
}

.gallery-item img {
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
}

.gallery-overlay {
 border:1px solid red;
 background-color:rgba(0,255,255,.5);
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
}

.gallery-overlay img {
  z-index: -1;
}

.gallery-caption {
 height:50px;
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="gallery clearfix col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-4 gallery-item">
      <div class="gallery-overlay">
       <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/" alt="500x500">
      </div>
      <p class="gallery-caption text-center">Item caption</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 gallery-item">
      <div class="gallery-overlay">
       <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/" alt="500x500">
      </div>
      <p class="gallery-caption text-center">Item caption</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 gallery-item">
      <div class="gallery-overlay">
       <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/" alt="500x500">
      </div>
      <p class="gallery-caption text-center">Item caption</p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!-- new row starts -->
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-4 gallery-item">
      <div class="gallery-overlay">
       <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/" alt="500x500">
      </div>
      <p class="gallery-caption text-center">Item caption</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 gallery-item">
      <div class="gallery-overlay">
       <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/" alt="500x500">
      </div>
      <p class="gallery-caption text-center">Item caption</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 gallery-item">
      <div class="gallery-overlay">
       <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/" alt="500x500">
      </div>
      <p class="gallery-caption text-center">Item caption</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: .gallery-item img { position:relative; width:100%; z-index:-1;} Just tried with the other z-indexes deleted, but still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `opacity` instead by changing the `background-color` for `gallery-overlay` to `rgba(255,255,255,1)` and adding `opacity: 0.1` to `gallery-item img` which will produce the exact same visual result.

Check the Code Snippet below:

```css
.gallery {
 margin-top:50px;
}

.gallery-item {
 padding:0px;
 border:1px solid white;
 z-index:101;
 position:relative;
}

.gallery-item img {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    z-index:101;
    opacity: 0.1;
}

.gallery-overlay {
 border:1px solid red;
 background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 z-index:102;
}

.gallery-caption {
 height:50px;
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="gallery clearfix col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-4 gallery-item">
      <div class="gallery-overlay">
       <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/" alt="500x500">
      </div>
      <p class="gallery-caption text-center">Item caption</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 gallery-item">
      <div class="gallery-overlay">
       <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/" alt="500x500">
      </div>
      <p class="gallery-caption text-center">Item caption</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 gallery-item">
      <div class="gallery-overlay">
       <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/" alt="500x500">
      </div>
      <p class="gallery-caption text-center">Item caption</p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!-- new row starts -->
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-4 gallery-item">
      <div class="gallery-overlay">
       <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/" alt="500x500">
      </div>
      <p class="gallery-caption text-center">Item caption</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 gallery-item">
      <div class="gallery-overlay">
       <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/" alt="500x500">
      </div>
      <p class="gallery-caption text-center">Item caption</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 gallery-item">
      <div class="gallery-overlay">
       <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/" alt="500x500">
      </div>
      <p class="gallery-caption text-center">Item caption</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: I would, but the background color doesn't work at all, so still pointless.

Comment: It works but you gave it an opcaity of 0.1 on the background rather than on the image. I reversed the properties by adding no opacity to the bg but rather to the image and it's working fine. Run the code snippet above and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: However that's kind of just a quick fix, it works well. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to replace `background-color` with just background ?

Like this :

```
.gallery-overlay {
    border:1px solid red;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,.1);
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    z-index:102;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but without any result unfortunately.

Comment: Try  this : 
.gallery-overlay {  border:1px solid red;  background-imager:rgba(255,255,255,.1);  position:relative;  width:100%;  z-index:102; }

Comment: Type on background-imager supposed to be background-image

Comment: Haha, I got it :) But still no effect.